# slider does not look good because of bootstrap local and cdn links

Tags: php, html, image, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

i have use a slider in the project in the index file, but it does not look good when the bootstrap renders it, Im new to coding, but i dont know what to do, when i write the code in single file and only cdn links (no offline libraries), like popper.min.js, jquery.min.js , bootstrap.min.css and bootstrap.min.js these files
the slider shows up but the images do not appear one after one,  i mean only the active image is shown

this is the header file some code that is automatically included in every file

```
    <!-- link proper font here, like signica, offline font -->
    <!--    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./bootstrap/css/bootstrap/signica-light.ttf">-->
    <!--    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./bootstrap/css/bootstrap/signica-bold.ttf">-->
    <!--    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./bootstrap/css/bootstrap/signica-regular.ttf">-->
    <!--    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./bootstrap/css/bootstrap/signica-semibold.ttf">-->
    <!--    -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./bootstrap/css/bootstrap/montserrat-regular.ttf">

    <!-- this title variable is written before the page executed -->
    <title><?php echo $title; ?></title>

    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/jpg" href="./bootstrap/img/favicon.png"/>

    <!-- enable these links when in production -->
<!--            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">-->
<!--            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
<!--            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>-->
<!--            <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>-->
    <!---->

    <link href="./bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!--    <link href="./bootstrap/js/popper.min.js" rel="stylesheet">-->
<!--    <link href="./bootstrap/js/jquery.min.js" rel="stylesheet">-->
<!--    <link href="./bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" rel="stylesheet">-->

    <link href="./bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="./bootstrap/css/jumbotron.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="./bootstrap/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

and this is the code of index file

```
<head>

    <style>
        .carousel-inner > .item > img,
        .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
            width: 100%;
            margin: auto;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<!-- slider starts -->

<div class="container">
    <br>
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="4"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="5"></li>
        </ol>

        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

            <div class="item active">
                <img src="./bootstrap/img/cs-1.jpg" alt="Chania" width="1300" height="600">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h3>Chania</h3>
                    <p>The atmosphere in Chania has a touch of Florence and Venice.</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <img src="./bootstrap/img/cs-2.jpg" alt="Chania" width="1300" height="600">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h3>Chania</h3>
                    <p>The atmosphere in Chania has a touch of Florence and Venice.</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <img src="./bootstrap/img/cs-3.jpg" alt="Flower" width="1300" height="600">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h3>Flowers</h3>
                    <p>Beautiful flowers in Kolymbari, Crete.</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <img src="./bootstrap/img/cs-4.jpg" alt="Flower" width="1300" height="600">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h3>Flowers</h3>
                    <p>Beautiful flowers in Kolymbari, Crete.</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <img src="./bootstrap/img/cs-5.jpg" alt="Chania" width="1300" height="600">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h3>Chania</h3>
                    <p>The atmosphere in Chania has a touch of Florence and Venice.</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <img src="./bootstrap/img/cs-6.jpg" alt="Chania" width="1300" height="600">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h3>Chania</h3>
                    <p>The atmosphere in Chania has a touch of Florence and Venice.</p>
                </div>
            </div>


        </div>

        <!-- Left and right controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>


    </div>
</div>

<!-- slider ends -->
```

and this is offline js

````
================================================== -->
<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="./bootstrap/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./bootstrap/js/popper.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>```


i dont know where the problem is[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVQZf.jpg
````

Comment: This makes no sense. Are you saying it only works properly when you use the local JS files? You didn't really clarify. Maybe they are different versions to the CDN ones. But either way, you need to decide whether to use CDNs, or use files deployed with the application. Don't switch between them for dev and production use, it just will cause issues.

Comment: In your production header you have all of your `<script>` tags commented out.  Bootstrap's Carousel component requires the Bootstrap JavaScript assets to be loaded.  Are you sure they are loading?

Comment: @ADyson, i mean the code works fine when I use the slider code and use only CDNs in another single html file (without project)
but inside project something disturbs it, im new to code 

Comment: the slider works fine when i put only the slider code with CDNs in a seperate independant  html file, i have tried to comment the offline libs and enable the cdn, nothing good happens

Comment: Do you understand how to open your browser's Developer Tools  and look in the Console for JavaScript errors (and in the Network tool for loading errors)? Maybe there are some clues there.

Comment: @ADyson ohh, yes i'll try with that caled "devloper tools"